# First page with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

Follow tutorial from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/3.1/page_creation.html). Here u can see my project and create Controller by follow tutorial:

Then I try with this URL `domain/Symfony/web/` and I get standard welcome page:

Then I try to allow my new controller from tutorial (first image) with this URL `web/lucky/number` and get this:

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>   Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

Then try without `/web` same error.

Comment: use the dev environnement to see the error

Comment: Can u explain me ?

Comment: He means use the development controller like `domain/Symfony/web/app_dev.php`. With this you should get a more informative error message, if the error occurs at all. If it works fine in dev environment it's probably just a cache problem and you need to clear the `prod` cache

Comment: You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.

Comment: how are you running the app ? using bin/console server:run ? or apache/nginx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to cmd and type:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod
```

if u use ftp and u can't use console, just delete

`Project/var/cache->all subfolders`, don't worry about that, Symfony is smart !

Comment: after deleting the folders `Project/var/cache->all subfolders` first time I see blank page with nothing to display. But on second time 404 error is comming.